# Unlimit the maximum concurrent connection on Windows 10

Tags: iis, tcp, windows-10

As you know windows 10 pro supports only 10 concurrent connections at a same time.
but my iis-hosted-app need more than that number connections. how can i unlimit this.

Comment: Did you try same solution as for windows7? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/ru-RU/18667011-c034-43bc-ab2e-0e87bf811e5e/windows-7-increase-the-limit-of-concurrent-tcp-connections-not-related-to-eula-file-sharing?forum=w7itpronetworking

Comment: For as far as I know, IIS on Windows 10 supports 20 concurrent connnections, not 10. This is a technical _and_ legal limitation. If you want more than that, use Windows Server.

Comment: i was able to do more then 50 connection bypassing the IIS. Using Web API Self host. On Windows 10

Comment: @Parv Sharma Can you explain a bit more? I have 5 computers trying to access 5 drivers on my workstation and since 1 driver = 1 connection I run over the 20 limit... any help would be great!

Comment: @Dariusz - ill be happy to help. If you want to dig a little deeper the problem wa with the WebListener. If you can change the implentation of weblisterner not using HttpSys your problem i think will be solved