# Does windows 10 connection limit apply to self-hosted applications?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, rabbitmq, windows-10

I am planning to run RabbitMQ on Windows 10 as well as other services, including Self-Hosted ASP.NET Application. I don't want to use Windows Server from reasons I don't want to explain here.

Will I have problems after hitting 10 concurrent connections limit of Windows 10?

Number of consumers can reach even 30-50.

Comment: You can also think about using it on the Internet Cloud, for example on Azure

Comment: Unfortunately I will be using it offline. No internet access. But thank you for information.

Comment: why don't you use linux instead?

Comment: because application is written in C#, it is not financially viable to rewrite it. I have tried to migrate it to .NET Core but it turns out that technology is very immature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Microsoft EULA for Windows 10:

> (iii)    Device connections. You may allow up to 20 other devices to access the software installed on the licensed device for the purpose of using the following software features: file services, print services, Internet information services, and Internet connection sharing and telephony services on the licensed device. You may allow any number of devices to access the software on the licensed device to synchronize data between devices. This section does not mean, however, that you have the right to install the software, or use the primary function of the software (other than the features listed in this section), on any of these other devices.

So, the limit isn't 10 connections.  The limit is enforced both as a legal obligation and programmatically for some services (e.g. IIS, but not self-hosted ASP.NET).

Since what you're asking about may involve the EULA, you should really get proper legal advice.

Sources:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Useterms/OEM/Windows/10/UseTerms_OEM_Windows_10_English.htm

[Unlimit the maximum concurrent connection on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38056200/unlimit-the-maximum-concurrent-connection-on-windows-10)

Comment: Thank you. Let me get this clear: Does it mean that there is no technical limitation  on concurrent connections when using self-hosted ASP. NET app or any other application?

Comment: Self-hosted ASP.NET isn't limited, other things (IIS) are, but I couldn't guarantee what the full list is.  To be really certain it would make sense to me to mock up a very simple test and try it out.

Comment: Thank you. Although I was expecting only answer to my question and not excerpt from Microsoft EULA, I will accept your answer.