# Why I am limited on concurrent HTTP connections using threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, http, iis-10

I'm trying to open about 25connections to a host at the same time.
My OS is windows 10.
For testing, I bring up a simple website on my local `IIS` and I response a simple data to the user with a delay of 2 seconds using `Thread.Sleep(2000)`.

Now using this code on the client:

```
const int len = 25;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart((idx) =>
    {
        // start downloading data.
        var res = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://192.168.1.101:8090/");

        // log index and time when done.
        Console.WriteLine($"{Convert.ToInt32(idx).ToString("00")} done at:{ DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:ffff") }");
    })).Start(i);
}
```

I got the following result:

```
Thread 01 done at 40:8476 ms
Thread 00 done at 40:8476 ms
Thread 03 done at 40:8496 ms
Thread 04 done at 40:8496 ms
Thread 02 done at 40:8506 ms
Thread 05 done at 40:8506 ms
Thread 07 done at 40:8516 ms
Thread 06 done at 40:8516 ms
Thread 08 done at 40:8536 ms
Thread 09 done at 40:8545 ms
Thread 11 done at 42:8510 ms
Thread 10 done at 42:8510 ms
Thread 12 done at 42:8560 ms
Thread 14 done at 42:8560 ms
Thread 15 done at 42:8570 ms
Thread 13 done at 42:8580 ms
Thread 16 done at 42:8590 ms
Thread 17 done at 42:8590 ms
Thread 18 done at 42:8610 ms
Thread 19 done at 42:8610 ms
Thread 21 done at 44:8565 ms
Thread 20 done at 44:8565 ms
Thread 23 done at 44:8634 ms
Thread 24 done at 44:8654 ms
Thread 22 done at 44:8654 ms
```

The above result tells us that:
1- `Thread 0 to 9` got the data at the same time.(second 40)
2- `Thread 10 to 19` got the data at the same time 2 seconds later after previous step.(second 42)
3- `Thread 20 to 24` got the data at the same time. 2 seconds later after previous step.(second 44)

Now my question is **WHO** limited me and **why** it only opens 10 `HTTP` connections at the same time and how can I set it to unlimited.
If there is any other platform or programming language it will be welcomed.

Comment: By the way, it's inefficent to use a thread for I/O, especially 1 thread per connection.  Look into _I/O Completion Ports_ or just use `async/await`

Comment: Run it on Windows Server and you should have a different outcome.

Comment: Must be something about your setup, mine ran differently, probably then number of cores +n as actually you're running 5 at a time

Comment: @BugFinder on which OS?

Comment: Win10, but if you look at the timing, yours started as a batch of 5 and then things were slotted in as they fitted.  What happens if you change them to tasks not threads

Comment: @BugFinder I'm not the OP. I don't think this has anything to do with threading. Do you perhaps have Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise? Perhaps they have different limits.

Comment: Im on Pro, but I remember reading something about workstation limiting threads

Comment: I hosted the app on a windows server 2016 with IIS-10 and the same result happened. running code in browser using `fetch()` function of the `javascript` also results the same and not opens 25 connection and gets the result after 2 seconds. @MickyD @CodeCaster @BugFinder @mxmissile

Answer (score 7):

Who? Your OS and web server manufacturer, being Microsoft.

Why? Because Windows 10 is a client OS, and Microsoft doesn't want you to host any serious web applications on that.

See for example:

- [Why is IIS allowing only 3 connections at the time?](https://serverfault.com/questions/800338/why-is-iis-allowing-only-3-connections-at-the-time)
- [Are there any connection limits on Windows 7 IIS v7.5?](https://serverfault.com/questions/21131/are-there-any-connection-limits-on-windows-7-iis-v7-5)
- [Maximum number of http-requests on IIS with Windows 7](https://forums.iis.net/t/1164347.aspx)

And from [While using signalr, will there be any connection limits on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667799/while-using-signalr-will-there-be-any-connection-limits-on-iis), linking to [the SignalR documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms):

> When SignalR is hosted in IIS, the following versions are supported. Note that if a client operating system is used, such as for development (Windows 8 or Windows 7), full versions of IIS or Cassini should not be used, since there will be a limit of 10 simultaneous connections imposed, which will be reached very quickly since connections are transient, frequently re-established, and are not disposed immediately upon no longer being used. **IIS Express should be used on client operating systems**.

There are other posts, like [Does windows 10 connection limit apply to self-hosted applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577869/does-windows-10-connection-limit-apply-to-self-hosted-applications), mentioning 20 connections, but that's 20 **devices** (probably recognized by remote IP address) connecting to **selected Windows service** (SMB, IIS, ...).

The IIS limit is 10, and has been for many years, I think since Windows 7.

So the first half of the answer to this question is:

- If you need more than 10 simultaneous *incoming* HTTP connections while developing on Windows 10, use IIS Express or any other web server than IIS or Cassini.

But there's a second half of this answer. If you need more than 10 (or 2, or ..., depending on the environment) simultaneous *outgoing* HTTP connections, there's ServicePointManager who manages this. See:

- [Trying to run multiple HTTP requests in parallel, but being limited by Windows (registry)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960056/trying-to-run-multiple-http-requests-in-parallel-but-being-limited-by-windows)
- [How can I programmatically remove the 2 connection limit in WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866350/how-can-i-programmatically-remove-the-2-connection-limit-in-webclient)
- Microsoft Docs: [Network Programming in the .NET Framework - Managing Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/managing-connections)

So change the limit before executing the requests:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 25;
```